# username is not a part of password and vice versa javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Password should not contain username or parts of the user's full name that exceed two consecutive characters

If username= 1Abcd234
   password= aBc15
then it should return error like password could not contain any parts of username.

Because "abc1" is present in both password and username.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please share your code.

Comment: And what have you tried to make this, please note that StackOverflow is not a coding service

Comment: Just loop through it and use indexof

Comment: Can you tell me how to loop in indexof.

Comment: I use this code

function check(user,pswd){
    use= user.toLowerCase();
    pwd= pswd.toLowerCase();
    var value= (pwd.match(/[a-z]+/ig).filter(a=> a.length > 1 && use.includes(a)).length > 0);
    return value; 
   }
   if(check("abcdefgh","abc1")==true){
    alert('true');
   }
   else
   {
    alert('false');
   }

But in this if I use username like abcsfgh then it return false.

Comment: "Levenshtein distance" algorithm is what you need

Comment: please check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36566052/5060513 it check between 2 strings similarity in ratio 0 to 1

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use something like this:

```js
function FindIntersectionFromStart(a,b){
    for(var i=a.length;i>0;i--){
        d = a.substring(0,i);
        j = b.indexOf(d);
        if (j>=0){
            return ({position:j,length:i});
        }
    }

    return null;
}

function FindIntersection(a,b){
    var bestResult = null;
    for(var i=0;i<a.length-1;i++){
        var result = FindIntersectionFromStart(a.substring(i),b);
        if (result){
            if (!bestResult){
                bestResult = result;
            } else {
                if (result.length>bestResult.length){
                    bestResult = result;
                }
            }
        }
        if(bestResult && bestResult.length>=a.length-i)
            break;
    }
    return bestResult;
}

var username = "myUsername";
var password = "myuse";

result = FindIntersection(username.toLowerCase(), password.toLowerCase());

if(result.length > 2){
  console.log("Invalid Password!");
} else {
  console.log("Valid Password!")
}
```

Comment: Sorry but if I use this
var username = "myUsername";
var password = "myuse";

It will return valid password .

Comment: @NishuKashyap this occurs because the cases are different.  By adding `.toLowerCase()` your example works.

Comment: Sorry but you don't get my point.
If myUsername and myuse both have same string i.e. myuse then how can return valid password.

Comment: @NishuKashyap I updated the code to meet your example.  Try it again.

Comment: Thank you so much. Now It works fine for me. @Derek Brown

Comment: @Kashyap this code currently does this- it returns valid iff there is no common substring with length greater than 2.

Comment: Yes I also get this. If you have any solution for this also then please let me know. Thanks again @Derek Brown

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple approach (may not be the best though):

1. First get all combinations of consecutive characters from `username` that should not be found in `password`. This would depend on the number of consecutive characters that your application considers invalid if matched.
2. Now, run a simple loop and check the presence of any of the invalid combinations using [String.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) method.
3. Make sure that you convert both - `username` and `password` to same case for simplicity.

```js
$("#check").on("click", checkValidity );

function checkValidity(){
  var numConsecutiveChars = 2;
  var username = $("#username").val().trim().toLowerCase();
  var password = $("#password").val().trim().toLowerCase();
  
  // first find all combinations that should not be found in password
  var invalidCombinations = [];
  for( var i = 0; i < username.length - numConsecutiveChars; i++ ){
    var curCombination = username[i] + username[i+1];
    invalidCombinations.push( curCombination );
  }//for
  
  // now check all invalidCombinations
  var invalid = false;
  for( var i = 0; i < invalidCombinations.length; i++ ){
    var curCombination = invalidCombinations[i];
    if( password.indexOf( curCombination ) !== -1 ){
      invalid = true;
      break;
    }
  }//for()
  
  if( invalid ){
    alert("Invalid password");
  }else{
    alert("Valid password");
  }
}//checkValidity()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="username" value="user" />
<input type="text" id="password" value="pass" />
<button id="check">Check validity</button>
```

Comment: Yes this code also works. Thank you so much. @mohit bhardwaj