# How to check substring in a string with fuzziness?

Tags: javascript

I have a string `akstr = My name is khan` and I want to know that does `akstr` contains `My name` which I can do easily but if I want to check does `akstr` contains `My nama` with little mistake in spelling and I want `True` as output. Could it be done using javascript?

Comment: maybe you could create a list of accepted words and do a find-replace of them and then check for 'My name'

Comment: That is not possible since database is huge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided you use node.js, you can use the npm package [natural](https://www.npmjs.com/package/natural).
It is used for natural language processing applications.
It has a set of methods for calculating String Distances. Meaning that `My name` is 94% equal to `My nama`. You can create your fuzzy algorithm based on that. An example:

```
const natural = require('natural');
let distance = natural.JaroWinklerDistance("My name", "My nama");
console.log(distance);
```

prints `0.9428571428571428`

You may find other intersting stuff in it too, like spell checking and Approximate String Matching.

With just javascript I wrote a simple fuzzy contains method with three inputs. The first is the full string, the second, the substring and the third the allowed error. In this case with an error 2, you allow 2 characters to be different for the substring. With 0 you get the normal contains method. You can also change the way the error is calculated (maybe a percentage based on the substring length). I used the code for the levenstein method from here: https://gist.github.com/andrei-m/982927

```js
function levenstein(a, b) {
    var m = [], i, j, min = Math.min;

    if (!(a && b)) return (b || a).length;

    for (i = 0; i <= b.length; m[i] = [i++]);
    for (j = 0; j <= a.length; m[0][j] = j++);

    for (i = 1; i <= b.length; i++) {
        for (j = 1; j <= a.length; j++) {
            m[i][j] = b.charAt(i - 1) == a.charAt(j - 1)
                ? m[i - 1][j - 1]
                : m[i][j] = min(
                    m[i - 1][j - 1] + 1, 
                    min(m[i][j - 1] + 1, m[i - 1 ][j] + 1))
        }
    }

    return m[b.length][a.length];
}
function fuzzyContains(a, b, error) {
    var matchLength = a.length - b.length;
    var distanceToMatch = levenstein(a, b) - matchLength;
    if(distanceToMatch - error > 0) {
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
}
console.log(fuzzyContains("hello world entire", "worlf", 1))
```

Comment: I'm not using node.js

Comment: https://github.com/thsig/jaro-winkler-JS check this if you want, it provides the same string distance functionality. There are other implementation in the internet too.

Comment: This is for comparing two strings. I want to check if a string contains a substring with fuzziness.

Comment: You said that you can do the contain part easily and your problem is in spelling mistakes

Comment: I said because in javascript I can use `includes` to check if string contains a substring but if there is a spelling mistake I will not work since `includes` checks letter by letter.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare the String, like

My Name
My Nama

is 90% matches so you can return true.

You will get more idea from the following link

[Compare Strings Javascript Return %of Likely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10473745/compare-strings-javascript-return-of-likely)

Comment: And how would I know that with what substring I would compare small string. Instead of `My nama` it could `iss khana` or `name ik` or `my name khan`?

Comment: 1st param can be Your database value and second can you input value