# Regex for best match

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a list of strings such as

```
const myCategories = ["Alligator", "Rhyno", "Elephant"]
```

And I want to get the best match for the string which I provide as input, for example

```
const userInput = "elep"

return myCategories.find(category => category.test(userInput))
```

However this does not work as I expect.

I need this to return a category even with a partial match, for example, if i write "eph", I should get "Elephant", or "rho" I should get "Rhyno"

Comment: You can use [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10473745/compare-strings-javascript-return-of-likely) to get the 'score' of each word, then show the one with the highest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What it sounds like you're looking for is not regex, but a fuzzy string comparison. Try [Javascript fuzzy search that makes sense](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23305000/javascript-fuzzy-search-that-makes-sense) for more information.