# How to do advanced string comparison in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, string, string-comparison

I am trying to compare 2 paragraphs of strings the output of which has to be the percentage of similarity.

I have tried doing this using the `diff` method and some `Natural Language Processing tools`

Is there a better way of doing this in ruby?

Comment: possible duplicate of [diff a ruby string or array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/80091/diff-a-ruby-string-or-array)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may want to try the Levenshtein string distance algorithm for this. http://rubygems.org/gems/text has an implementation of this along with other helpful string comparison utils.

Comment: Found one more gem.. A high level gem called English http://english.rubyforge.org/ .. Maybe it uses the Text gem

Answer (score 1):

See my similar Question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/797688/how-to-determine-a-strings-dna-for-likeness-to-another) what I needed but did not know what it was called was a [Levenshtein distance algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)