# Ruby compare two strings similarity percentage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, text

Id like to compare two strings in Ruby and find their similarity

I've had a look at the `Levenshtein` gem but it seems this was last updated in 2008 and I can't find documentation how to use it. With some blogs suggesting its broken

I tried the `text` gem with Levenshtein but it gives an integer (smaller is better)

Obviously if the two strings are of variable length I run into problems with the Levenshtein Algorithm (Say comparing two names, where one has a middle name and one doesnt).

What would you suggest I do to get a percentage comparison?

**Edit: Im looking for something similar to PHP's [similar text](http://php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php)**

Comment: possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4761793/how-to-do-advanced-string-comparison-in-ruby

Comment: This generates a list of differences, im looking for a % similarity

Comment: If the strings are of different length, which one should be taken as the base for calculating the percentage?

Comment: The longer one would be better? Im trying to go through a list of names to match ones from one column to another to the highest likeness (the ones on one side have middle names or dashes)

Comment: possible to use levenshtein copmarison and convert it to percents, as it is suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10405440/percentage-rank-of-matches-using-levenshtein-distance-matching

Comment: Good answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16323571/measure-the-distance-between-two-strings-with-ruby

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think your question could do with some clarifications, but here's something quick and dirty (calculating as percentage of the longer string as per your clarification above):

```
def string_difference_percent(a, b)
  longer = [a.size, b.size].max
  same = a.each_char.zip(b.each_char).count { |a,b| a == b }
  (longer - same) / a.size.to_f
end
```

I'm still not sure how much sense this percent difference you are looking for makes, but this should get you started at least.

It's a bit like Levensthein distance, in that it compares the strings character by character. So if two names differ only by the middle name, they'll actually be very different.

Comment: Can someone explain the 'same' bit? So it loops over each character, while the zip create an array for each character in string A with - what I would expect would be - every character in string B. How does the second each_char know what index to concatenate into the array?

Comment: Also, this calculation doesn't work well when there is one character changed at the beginning.

Comment: Beware of the **a** in the Select, because it clears the variable passed by parameter. It is better to use other letters.

`same = a.each_char.zip(b.each_char).select{ |c,d| c == d }.size`

Comment: It just shadows it inside the block.

Comment: `same = a.each_char.zip(b.each_char).count{ |c,d| c == d }`

Comment: Will return a range between 0 and 1. if 0 it's ico, if 1 it's completely different

Answer (score 17):

There is now a ruby gem for similar_text. https://rubygems.org/gems/similar_text
It provides a `similar` method that compares two strings and returns a number representing the percent similarity between the two strings.

Comment: similar_text gem freezes on big strings, tried 143kb html page

Answer (score 15):

I can recommend the [`fuzzy-string-match`](https://github.com/kiyoka/fuzzy-string-match) gem.

You can use it like this (taken from [the docs](https://github.com/kiyoka/fuzzy-string-match#native-version)):

```
require "fuzzystringmatch"
jarow = FuzzyStringMatch::JaroWinkler.create(:native)
p jarow.getDistance("jones", "johnson")
```

It will return a score `~0.832` which tells how good those strings match.