# How to compare these strings in python?

Tags: python, string, compare, hex

I have the following string:

```
1679.2235398,-1555.40390834,-1140.07728186,-1999.85500108
```

and I'm using a steganography technique to store it in an image. Now when I retrieve it back out of the image, sometimes I got it back in a complete form and I have no issue with that. Where in other occasions, the retrieved data are not fully retrieved (due to a modification/alteration being occurred on the image), so the result something look like this:

```
1679.2235398,-1555.I8\xf3\x1cj~\x9bc\x13\xac\x9e8I>[a\xfdV#\x1c\xe1\xea\xa0\x8ah\x02\xed\xd1\x1c\x84\x96\xe2\xfbk*8'l
```

Notice that, only "1679.2235398,-1555." are correctly retrieved, while the rest is where the modification has been occurred.
Now, how do I compute (in percentage) how much I successfully retrieved? 
Since the length is not the same, I can't do a character by character comparison , it seems that I need to slice or convert the modified data into some other form to match the length of the original data.

Any tips?

Comment: Does it not work to use the percentage of the original string that shows in the output?

Comment: No sure I've got what you mean, but what I want is something like this: is 1=1, is 6=6, and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of this is going to depend on the context of your problem, but you have a number of options here.

If your results always look like that, you could just find the [longest common subsequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem), then divide by the length of the original string for a percentage.

[Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) is a common way of comparing strings, as the number of characters required to change to turn one string into another. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10405440/percentage-rank-of-matches-using-levenshtein-distance-matching) has several answers discussing how to turn that into a percentage.

If you don't expect the strings to always come out in the same order, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21068904/2201041) suggests some algorithms used for DNA work.

Comment: Very interesting methods. I'm going to try both of them and see how the results look. Thanks JERM

Answer (score 0):

Well it really depends.. My solution would be something like this:

I would start with all the longest string possible and check if they are in the new string

`if original_string in new_string:
     'something happens here'.`

that would be inside a loop that wld decrease the size of the original string and get all combinations possible. so the next one wld be `N-1` long and have 2 possible combinations (cutting off the first number or the last number), and so on, until u get to a specific threshold, or to `1` long strings. 
 the loop can store the longest string you find in a log inside the if conditional, and afterward you can just check the results. hope that helps.

Comment: It seems this is a good approach to tackle it. Many thanks I will test it.