# Elasticsearch single word similarity

Tags: elasticsearch, diff, similarity

What are the options for single word similarity check?

Consider the following case: we have documents where field **email**, is present. When new document is added we want to check if there are any documents where email is similar to the new one with some similarity constraint - for example 80% match.

Are there any specific built in queries which can be used?

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `Fuzzy Query`, where you can provide your search string and Levenshtein distance in parameter `fuzziness`.
[Query reference here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-fuzzy-query.html)

Also to calculate Levenshtein distance from percentage, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10405440/percentage-rank-of-matches-using-levenshtein-distance-matching) might be helpful.

Comment: The maximum allowed Levenshtein Edit Distance in elasticsearch is 2. Thus Fizzy Query won't work in current case.