# Making two strings match even if one of them contains typo

Tags: ruby, regex

I ve got an array_subscribed_players and I am checking if this array includes a string this way:

```
array_subscribed_players.include?(subscription.user.full_name_inversed.downcase.strip)
```

I am looking for a way to make this expression return `true` even if the string that I give does not match perfectly with the string contained in `array_subscribed_players`. Let's say if there are one or two different letters or if it has one extra or less letter.

Comment: Bob Jones & Rob Bones match? only two letters different but clearly not a typo. NLP is not possible with regex, but you can do a crude match to match if two letters are different, but you're going to get some pretty inaccurate results

Answer (score 0):

You might do best with a gem that does fuzzy searching, with such methods as trigrams, and then experimenting with what you consider to be a high enough score to count as a match.

Various gems are available: look for trigram, fuzzy match, etc.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a fuzzy match algorithm. You can start using the [solution suggested in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9822078/ruby-compare-two-strings-similarity-percentage) or one of the various fuzzy matching Ruby implementations.

Once you have the algorithm in place (packaged as a method), simply call that method on each item of the array rather than using the standard string equality.

Answer (score 0):

You could utilize the gem similar text. It provides a % similar to compared to two strings. You'd have to build the logic for what % similarity you are looking for.

https://rubygems.org/gems/similar_text