# Jquery/JavaScript String Match

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have compare Two strings.If str1 matches 80% of str2 then it should return true. else it should return false.
 Please help me to Find the solution.
Thanks,

Comment: Please give examples. If not, this question will likely be closed very quickly

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to determine a strings dna for likeness to another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/797688/how-to-determine-a-strings-dna-for-likeness-to-another)

Comment: What does 80% match mean?  This problem is not solvable without some sort of definition of what an 80% match is or do you just want us to make up our own definition of an 80% match.

Comment: Try to introduce in more details, you need to give some criteria, for this task. for example "Hello world" and "world Hello". Are those strings matches 80% ?

Comment: View this may be help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4919403/javascript-compare-strings-without-being-case-sensitive

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`similar_text()`](http://phpjs.org/functions/similar_text:902) which behaves almost like [PHP's equivalent similar_text()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php)

Comment: But In javascript is that possible?

Comment: Yes, http://phpjs.org/functions/similar_text:902 this is the link. It doesn't give off percentages but you can calculate it from string length.